# Cargo Train Deluxe (7898) not running

Tags: trains, city, remote-control

I was working with the main locomotive of set 7898. I put brand new batteries in both the controller and locomotive but for some reason every time I press the button to turn on the train, the red light comes on and I press the button to make the train to go and nothing happens.

Any idea what the issue could be or how I can fix this?

Comment: Please check the possible duplicate answer. If your answer isn't found there, please edit your question with details to help us troubleshoot it.

Comment: I believe that the answer you referenced is for PF trains and the issue here is with an RC train.

Comment: While the referenced duplicate is for Power Functions, the steps to diagnose the issue are fairly similar - ensure that you have good line of sight between the controller and the receivers on the sides of the engine, check the motors still work in the wheel units with a direct connection to some batteries, etc. The set is about 10 years old, so some wear and tear may be expected.